# AWS direct connect BGP issue

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp, aws

[image]

This is out current setup and everything working great!!! here, now i want backup link for AWS so i have request for one more secondary link and terminated on `Cisco ASA` on `Port-channel1.8` interface.

```
asa/pri/act# sh run int po1.8
!
interface Port-channel1.8
 description ### AWS-DX-2 ###
 vlan 8
 nameif aws_dx_2
 security-level 0
 ip address 169.254.8.1 255.255.255.248 standby 169.254.8.3

asa/pri/act# sh run int po1.9
!
interface Port-channel1.9
 description ### AWS-DX-1 ###
 vlan 9
 nameif aws_dx
 security-level 0
 ip address 169.254.9.1 255.255.255.248 standby 169.254.9.3
```

This is my BGP config

```
router bgp 65501
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 timers bgp 10 30 0
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  neighbor 169.254.8.2 remote-as 7224
  neighbor 169.254.8.2 password *****
  neighbor 169.254.8.2 activate
  neighbor 169.254.8.2 route-map BGP-LOCAL-PREF in
  neighbor 169.254.8.2 route-map BGP-AS-PREPEND out
  neighbor 169.254.9.2 remote-as 7224
  neighbor 169.254.9.2 password *****
  neighbor 169.254.9.2 activate
  network 10.10.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0
  network 10.20.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0
  network 10.30.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0
  distribute-list ACL-BGP-IN in
  no auto-summary
  no synchronization
 exit-address-family
!
```

My route-map

```
asa/pri/act# sh run route-map
!
route-map BGP-LOCAL-PREF permit 10

 set local-preference 90
!
route-map BGP-AS-PREPEND permit 10

 set as-path prepend 65501 65501 65501
!
```

So far so good till here in BGP summery

```
Neighbor        V           AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ Up/Down  State/PfxRcd
169.254.8.2     4         7224 76      61            15    0    0 00:10:49  4
169.254.9.2     4         7224 286     225           15    0    0 00:41:45  4
```

Now problem start here, from my LAN i can't ping AWS any instance.

If i go ahead and shutdown one of link then my LAN hosts can ping AWS instance, I am trying to create redendency here and somehow its not working, Did i miss something here?

As soon as i do following it works..

```
neighbor 169.254.8.2 shutdown
```

I heard we shouldn't use `169.254/16` in local-link, do you think that could be the issue here?

## UPDATE -1

```
  Gateway of last resort is 74.XX.XX.107 to network 0.0.0.0

    S*       0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [1/0] via 74.XX.XX.107, outside
    S        10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0 [1/0] via 10.5.0.1, site1
    C        10.5.0.0 255.255.248.0 is directly connected, site1
    L        10.5.3.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, site1
    S        10.5.8.0 255.255.248.0 [1/0] via 10.5.0.1, site1
    S        10.5.16.0 255.255.248.0 [1/0] via 10.5.0.1, site1
    S        10.5.255.0 255.255.255.0 [1/0] via 10.5.0.1, site1
    C        10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0 is directly connected, dmz_ext
    L        10.10.0.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, dmz_ext
    C        10.20.0.0 255.255.0.0 is directly connected, dmz_int
    L        10.20.0.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, dmz_int
    C        10.30.0.0 255.255.0.0 is directly connected, inside
    L        10.30.0.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, inside
    C        10.40.0.0 255.255.0.0 is directly connected, pxe
    L        10.40.0.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, pxe
    B        10.100.4.0 255.255.252.0 [20/0] via 169.254.9.2, 00:50:35
    C        74.XX.XX.0 255.255.254.0 is directly connected, public
    L        74.XX.XX.10 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, public
    C        74.XX.XX.104 255.255.255.248 is directly connected, outside
    L        74.XX.XX.110 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, outside
    C        169.254.8.0 255.255.255.248 is directly connected, aws_dx_2
    L        169.254.8.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, aws_dx_2
    C        169.254.9.0 255.255.255.248 is directly connected, aws_dx
    L        169.254.9.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, aws_dx
    C        172.29.0.0 255.255.0.0 is directly connected, ilo
    L        172.29.0.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, ilo
    C        192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 is directly connected, FailoverLink
    L        192.168.100.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, FailoverLink
```

If you notice i have only single BGP route in my table.

```
B        10.100.4.0 255.255.252.0 [20/0] via 169.254.9.2, 00:58:40
```

## Update -2

I did clear asp drop and now seeing this.

```
Frame drop:
  No valid adjacency (no-adjacency)                                           12
  Flow is denied by configured rule (acl-drop)                               133
  First TCP packet not SYN (tcp-not-syn)                                      54
  TCP RST/FIN out of order (tcp-rstfin-ooo)                                    4
  Slowpath security checks failed (sp-security-failed)                         1
  ICMP Inspect seq num not matched (inspect-icmp-seq-num-not-matched)         31
  FP L2 rule drop (l2_acl)                                                   270
```

Comment: Using 169.254/16 is OK.  The problem is likely asymmetric traffic and the ASA is blocking it (e.g., traffic goes out VL 8 and returns VL 9.  Please post the show route from the ASA

Comment: If you're using BGP, the chances are good that you're dealing with an Asymmetric path outbound vs inbound, which could play havoc with your Cisco ASA (if you aren't NAT'ing traffic).  Does this sound possible?

Comment: First time i am using ASA for BGP and i did set LOCAL-PREF and PREPEND to make one of my link backup link then how come its doing `Asymmetric path` ?? I am not doing NATing, Can you give me clue or troubleshooting method to find out, also i have single BGP route in my table

Comment: According to your routes, VL 9 is your outbound path. You can do the same on your AWS console to see what your return path is. I assume it's VL8.
You need to prepend your AS on VL 8 so VL 9 is preferred.

Comment: How do you know that Amazon has selected the same preferred egress path that you want them to?  Did you talk to them and confirm that's what they've done?  Ignore the concern about 169.254/16... yes, it's a strange address.  No, it's not a problem... seriously, we are only the hundred-thousandth Amazon customer using such

Comment: @MikePennington A parallel conversation is going on in chat.

Comment: But i am sending `prepend` PATH to aws BGP so it should make that link secondary.. am i missing anything here?

Comment: Things are not working, so something is still wrong.  It's possible that Amazon is rewriting your inbound attributes, or they simply configured their side with attributes that override AS-path length (such as local-pref).  If you don't want to futz with BGP on both sides, NAT your traffic outbound to Amazon (on both links - different addrs) and be done with it

Comment: I have updated my question with `PREPEND` and `LOCAL-PREF` which i forgot to add them

Comment: on AWS console i am not seeing any BGP related option where i can play.. on Documents they are saying use `PREPEND` AS_PATH here is the document https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/active-passive-direct-connect/

Comment: Ok, so knowing they honor AS-path length is good... did you add both 169.254.x subnets in your IGP?

Comment: IGP? we have no igp running on ASA

Comment: So is the ASA the only thing doing routing for your entire ASN?

Comment: my ASA directly connected to my LAN and i want my LAN talk to AWS.. very simple network

Comment: Have you checked whether the ASA is logging dropped traffic for some reason? 'show asp drop' may help

Comment: @MikePennington I have updated question with `asp drop`

Comment: Try flipping the as prepend to the other peer and see if that helps

Comment: @MikePennington do you think this could be an issue - http://finkotek.com/cisco-asa-ha-failure-due-to-overlapping-ip/

Comment: Quoting the link: “Do not use link local addresses on the failover interface”.  Sorry for typos, I’m on my mobile... bottom line I don’t think you put 169.254 on your failover interface did you?  Keep with this, it seems like we’re starting to make progress.  To make it short, I’m wondering if you set up failover right.  We can do basic tests or you post all the configurations.  It’s been a while since I touched ASA (we run Palos now).  I was going to get this “working “ and then pull all interfaces / power cords one at a time

Comment: If you go the route of posting all your config make sure you label all the interfaces on your diagrams that may not be a bad idea anyway

Comment: @MikePennington WHO ARE YOU? Because i think you are goddamn awesome!!! as soon as i put `prepend` and `local pref` to VLAN 9 `Port-channel1.9` and everything works :)  I really want you to explain me.. and please post answer i would like to give you +1

Comment: I’m driving to dinner with somebody tonight but I’ll try to catch up on this over the weekend

Comment: FYI, i didn't put any `169.254.0.0/16` subnet on any failover link or anywhere else.

Comment: @satish, I'm curious is your Cisco ASA pair in Active-Standby or Active-Active mode?

Comment: `Active-standby`

Comment: have you *ever* used static routing with Amazon?

Comment: You meant to say try static route instead of BGP? No I didn't try that, also do you think one of BGP peer not honoring prepend attribute ?

Comment: Well I don’t think it’s a bgp bug but part of the story doesn’t add up.  I asked you to swap prepends as a diagnostic tool but I still don’t see root cause yet.  How were you testing connectivity?  Ping from the fw or some other technique?  Please be specific about source and destination address and where you tested from

Comment: Source is my LAN host (10.10.x.x/16) and destination is AWS EC2 instance (10.100.4.0/22), for testing i am doing ping, ssh, and running test on my client/server application, I am not testing any ping from `asa` fw,  If its not ASA fault then it must be something wrong in AWS end.

Comment: There is something forcing VPC egress traffic over Po1.8... it could be that someone borked a route-filter, or didn't set up iBGP right.  Anyway, I don't see a problem on your side, but it's hard to be sure if you don't post _all_ the configs and label _all_ the ports

Comment: I am planning to open ticket to AWS to find out what is going on and will update you, I will send you direct config of asa on your email in worst case to just avoid legal mumbo jumbo!

Comment: Curiousity: Did you solve this problem?  If so, post an answer below with what solved it

Comment: @MikePennington sorry we did open ticket but they are slow because we have intermediate partner who gave us `DX` so kind of slow reply.. i will update you but i think you and port your answer anyway, if any modification required i will show update here.

Comment: can you update the post with what is the final diagnosis? I'd be curious to see how in an active-active config with two different routers work statefully. That is, can we achieve if traffic sent on router 1 is returned on router 1 and traffic sent on router 2 is returned on router 2. Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would check to see where return traffic from AWS is going.  If having both links turned up causes traffic to stop flowing though your ASA then there is a good chance that you have asymmetric routing.  Depending on the logging level on your ASA there should be a bunch of half formed connection errors in logging as well.